handling issue when appending values to file - python
I've got an unwanted outcome occurring when adding data to an existing txt file. I want to add new data to an existing file and export it to the same location.
The file exists and it'll identify the data. But when I export it, all old data is overwritten and only the newly appended data exists.
The script is run using task scheduler. When I run it manually, it works as intended. Data will continue to append. But when it's on scheduler, I only ever get overwritten data.
def datafile():

    var1 =  #some val
    var2 =  #some val
    var3 =  #some val

    new_vars = [var1,var2,va3]

    with open(r"\\path\to\file\datafile.txt", 'r') as file:
        data = json.load(file)

    data.append(new_vars)

    with open(r"\\path\to\file\datafile.txt", 'w') as output:
       json.dump(data, output)

datafile()


The obvious answer is that path_to_file\datafile.txt does not exist.  We can't really be more specific without seeing your exact file structure and the original full exception message.  As a debugging step, temporarily remove the try/except handling altogether, and just let the first exception happen.  Then edit the question and add that message.

Is path_to_file\datafile.txt an absolute path, or is it relative to the current directory?  i.e. is it like /path/to/my/datafile.txt (with a leading slash), or is it like subdir/datafile.txt (without a leading slash) ?

Thanks. This comment cleared it up after investigating

Leading slash. Absolute path. Weirdly, I corrected the path but it only works intermittently. It creates a new file every other time. I'm running it from diff servers but on the same network. My actual path is (r\\file\path\to\my\datafile.txt")

What happens when you use only one "with open" with 'w+' ?
with open(r"\\path\to\file\datafile.txt", 'w+') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
    data.append(new_vars)
    json.dump(data, file)

